Editing the labels for a matplotlib colorbar
I am creating an XY plot of two values and shading them based on timestamps. I am trying to edit the labels/ticks on the colorbar, but when I edit the labels I either lose the colorbar, the labels dont come through correctly or a mixture of both. Ideally, I want to create ~6 ticks based on the start and end time of the data I am plotting.
enter image description here
code I am currently using:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

# Generate a range of timestamps
start_date = '2023-01-01'
end_date = '2023-01-31'
timestamps = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='h')  # hourly frequency

# Generate random numbers
np.random.seed(0)  # for reproducibility
random_numbers1 = np.random.rand(len(timestamps))
random_numbers2 = np.random.rand(len(timestamps))

# Create a DataFrame with the generated data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': timestamps,
    'RandomValue1': random_numbers1,
    'RandomValue2': random_numbers2
})

# Convert the Timestamp column to datetime format
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

# Create the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sc = plt.scatter(df['RandomValue1'], df['RandomValue2'], c=df['Timestamp'], cmap='viridis', alpha=0.5)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, label='Time')
plt.xlabel('Random Values')
plt.ylabel('Random Values')
plt.title(f'Plot of Random Values shaded by Time')

# Convert timestamps to numerical values
num_timestamps = mdates.date2num(df['Timestamp'])

# Customize the colorbar ticks and labels to reflect timestamps
num_ticks = 6  # Number of ticks you want on the colorbar
ticks = pd.date_range(start=df['Timestamp'].min(), end=df['Timestamp'].max(), periods=num_ticks)
cbar.set_ticks(mdates.date2num(ticks))
cbar.set_ticklabels([tick.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for tick in ticks])

plt.show()


Try out this updated code. This code creates a well-labelled colorbar with approximately 6 evenly spaced ticks corresponding to their timestamps. Let me know if it helps.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

# Generate a range of timestamps
start_date = '2023-01-01'
end_date = '2023-01-31'
timestamps = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='h')  # hourly frequency

# Generate random numbers
np.random.seed(0)  # for reproducibility
random_numbers1 = np.random.rand(len(timestamps))
random_numbers2 = np.random.rand(len(timestamps))

# Create a DataFrame with the generated data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': timestamps,
    'RandomValue1': random_numbers1,
    'RandomValue2': random_numbers2
})

# Convert the Timestamp column to datetime format
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

# Create the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sc = plt.scatter(df['RandomValue1'], df['RandomValue2'], c=mdates.date2num(df['Timestamp']), cmap='viridis', alpha=0.5)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, label='Time')
plt.xlabel('Random Values')
plt.ylabel('Random Values')
plt.title('Plot of Random Values shaded by Time')

# Customize the colorbar ticks and labels
num_ticks = 6  # Number of ticks you want on the colorbar
ticks = pd.date_range(start=df['Timestamp'].min(), end=df['Timestamp'].max(), periods=num_ticks)
tick_positions = mdates.date2num(ticks)  # Convert to numerical positions
cbar.set_ticks(tick_positions)
cbar.set_ticklabels([tick.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for tick in ticks])

plt.show()

How this code works:
The code generates 6 evenly spaced datetime ticks using pd.date_range. mdates.date2num() converts these ticks to numerical values and stores in the variable tick_positions. cbar.set_ticks(tick_positions) sets the colorbar ticks and cbar.set_ticklabels() applies the formatted labels.
Basically: The timestamps are turned into numbers so they can be used in the plot, and the colorbar is set up with evenly spaced markers that show the times in a clear, readable format. This makes it easy to match the colorbar to the data and understand what it represents.

Could you state which line(s) you changed and why it works?

Sure, i'll edit it with an explanation on how it works.

The bit you explained creates the ticks, but that code appears to be the same as given in the original question.  Could you explain the bit that is different from the original question?
